# Django - admin_order_field with custom non-related object

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-queryset

How can I use admin_order_field in a method, that has an opposite kind of relation?

Is it possible to use some aggregating query-set function?

```
class Card(models.Model):
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...

class License(models.Model):
    expiration = models.DateTimeField('Expiration')
    card = models.ForeignKey('Card')
    ...

class Pc(models.Model):
    card = models.ForeignKey('Card')
    ...

class PcAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

    def expiration(self, obj):
        try:
            license = License.objects.get(card=obj.card, type="xxx")
            expiration = license.expiration

        except (License.DoesNotExist, TypeError):
            expiration = "N/A"

        return expiration
    expiration.short_description = _("Expiration")
    expiration.admin_order_field = ???
```

Comment: what kind of aggregating query-set function you want to use?

Comment: aggregate sorted queryset, but the point is, that I want to order custom expiration field in the PcAdmin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, if you can refer to something the way you do a field, you can use it in `admin_order_field`.

So, if you wanted to order by the `Card's` `serial_number` you could say `admin_order_field = 'card__serial_number'.

Or, if you wanted to use annotations, you could do that by first defining a [`get_queryset()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) method that creates the annotation; and then using the new annotation name as your `admin_order_field`.

But in your case, you can't do it. The problem is the restriction to `type="xxx"`; there's no way to represent that logic using the field notation.

It might be possible, though, to use [`extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) to define a custom field with the information you want, and then use that as your `admin_order_field`.

Comment: is there a way to do it without editing db model? Like make a property to store sorted queryset and then use it in admin_order_field?

Comment: @Niorko: I don't think so. The ordering is done at the database level, so I don't think using a property will work.

Comment: Caution on using the `extra()` mentioned above. The Django docs state that it is planned to deprecate this in a future release.